# Parse, Displaying Usernames

Tags: parse-platform

I'm looking to display the usernames of every user in my Data Browser,
However, I am unsure of how to proceed. Would it be best if I did:

```
searchUsers.find({
            success: function(results) {
              for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var names = results[i].getUsername();
              }   
          }
        });
```

or

```
var user = Parse.User(); 
        user.fetch().then(function(fetchedUser){
                var names = fetchedUser.getUsername();         
         });
```

and where would I proceed from that?
I'm simply looking to append divs of each of the usernames, so something like:

```
$('body').append('<p>' + names + '</p>');
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do a combination of what you wrote.

```
searchUsers.find({
    success: function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
            var displayName = results[i].getUsername();
            $('body').append('<p>' + displayName + '</p>');
        }   
    }
});
```